# What is the current date in New York?

Tags: mysql

How do I fix this query to select the current date, in YYYY-MM-DD format, in New York?

```sql
SELECT CURDATE(); // sometimes returns the current date in New York, sometimes does not
```

My reporting software does not allow me to use `SET` or other statements or configuration options. I can only execute a single `SELECT` query. Is it possible to get the correct answer in the format above?

Answer (score 3):

```
select date(convert_tz(now(), @@time_zone, 'America/New_York'))
```

but verify that the mysql server has timezone information installed by doing:

```
select * from mysql.time_zone_name where Name='America/New_York';
```